# RabbitMQ federation example

Tags: rabbitmq, policy, federation, upstream

I have a scenario where I want to copy messages from multiple virtual hosts queues to the one virtual host queue. I have been trying to read and figured out that exchange and/or queues  federation is a good solution.
Can someone please illustrate me with the example, how can I accomplish that.

I have tried to set federation-upstream-set ALL. But I guess I am missing how to create a link. A concrete step by step example will be really helpful.
Thanks.